# Problem compiling when I use symbols less than or greater than

Tags: math-mode, babel, breqn

I am writing a document with Texmaker and when I write some equation with the less than (<) or greater than (>) symbols, then it doesn't compile (it doesn't end compiling and I don't get error message).

If I write the equation without one of these symbols all is correct and the program compile.
I have no idea why that happens.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\lstset{breakatwhitespace=false}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{breqn}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\lstset{
literate=%
         {á}{{\'a}}1
         {í}{{\'i}}1
         {é}{{\'e}}1
         {ó}{{\'o}}1
         {ú}{{\'u}}1
         {ñ}{{\~n}}1
         {Á}{{\'A}}1
         {Í}{{\'I}}1
         {É}{{\'E}}1
         {Ó}{{\'O}}1
         {Ú}{{\'U}}1
         {Ñ}{{\~N}}1
         {¿}{{?`}}1
         {¡}{{!`}}1
}
\begin{document}
$D_{P} < D < D_{o}$
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show us an example? Make a copy of your file, remove all the text except one such equation, and remove as much as code you can from the preamble without removing the problem. Can you also say which error you get?

Comment: Edited. The problem is in the math text at the end

Comment: If you reduce the preamble, you end up with `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
$<$
\end{document}`. Remove either `babel` or `breqn` and it works. Do you use `breqn` elsewhere?

Comment: I have removed the '\usepackage{breqn}' and it worked. I thought I used it but finally not. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reduce your example further, you end up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
$<$
\end{document}
```

So there is some interaction with `breqn` and `babel` which causes the problem. If no features of the `breqn` package are used, you can just remove `\usepackage{breqn}`.

However, it appears that this is a case where the loading order of packages matter; by swapping the order the example works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
$<$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in making `babel-spanish` and `breqn` into cooperating with each other.

With `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`, the `<` character is made active, to mean

```
\es@use@shorthand <
```

This command transforms `<` into an other character via `\string` when LaTeX is in certain states or else executes the associated shorthand.

When in math, we of course want `<` to behave like the “less than” symbol, so `\string<` is applied which, in normal settings will do the right thing.

Not so when `breqn` is loaded, because it makes `<` into a *math active* character. This means that when `<` with category code 12 is found, TeX replaces it with its meaning as an active character. Well, the meaning as an active character is what has just been explained, so `<` is replaced by `\string<` which becomes a category code 12 `<`, so its meaning as an active character is used…

*Oops! Infinite loop!*

Loading `breqn` before `babel` is a solution, because in this case `babel` knows that there is already a meaning for `<` as an active character and uses it in math mode.

On the other hand, the features provided by `<` as a shorthand are very limited and the manual for `babel-spanish` says

> Las incompatibilidades potenciales de estas abreviaciones son enormes.

(The potential incompatibilities of these shorthands are enormous.) So the best is to load

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
```

and forget about this (mis)feature.

---

Unrelated, but important. Your preamble is rather confusing, as it mixes package loading with setup.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}

% language and input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % compulsory for Spanish
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}

% math facilities
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % already loads amsfonts
\usepackage{breqn}

% other facilities
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig} % subfigure is obsolete

% non CTAN package
%\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}

%%% Settings

% pagination
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

% generic
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

% bibliography
\bibliographystyle{plain}

% listings
\lstset{breakatwhitespace=false}
\lstset{
literate=%
         {á}{{\'a}}1
         {í}{{\'i}}1
         {é}{{\'e}}1
         {ó}{{\'o}}1
         {ú}{{\'u}}1
         {ñ}{{\~n}}1
         {Á}{{\'A}}1
         {Í}{{\'I}}1
         {É}{{\'E}}1
         {Ó}{{\'O}}1
         {Ú}{{\'U}}1
         {Ñ}{{\~N}}1
         {¿}{{?`}}1
         {¡}{{!`}}1
}
```

Note that I changed `subfigure` into `subfig`, as the former is obsolete. Check the documentation of the latter package. You may want to use the more powerful `subcaption` package, though.

I commented out the call to `mcode`, because I don't have it.

Instead of setting `\baselinestretch` directly, you should consider using the `setspace` package (assuming you *have* to use large leading).

Comment: same with babel-french + mathtools with centercolon which makes the colon math active. Loading `mathastext` solves the issue as it knows how to correctly handle Babel active characters. This general issue should be solved upstream at level of Babel package which should check in math mode for math activation and provide language authors an interface for what to do then.